# How do i save files in a dyanamic location in PHP Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I want to save files to directories based on company id like if company has id of 11 then it should create a folder of same name and save/upload the files there?
I have my controller logic here but i dont know how to pass my company id which is in Company Model to saveAs() function.

Scene: I have list of companies from different model and i want to create a directory according to company id/name where the respective layout gets saved.

[image: List of Companies and Layout]

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $company=Company::find()->all();
    $model = new Layouts();
   

    // if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    //     return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->layout_id]);
    // }

    $model->setScenario('create');

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->layouts=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'layouts');
        if(!empty($model->layouts)){
            $filename=time()."_layouts".".". $model->layouts->extension;

            $model->layouts->saveAs('@app/web/uploads/layouts/'.$filename); //here i want it to be @app/web/uploads/layouts/company-id/filename
            $model->layouts=$filename;
            $model->created_by=Yii::$app->user->id;
            $model->updated_by=Yii::$app->user->id;
        }else{
            var_dump($model->errors);die;
        }

        if($model->save()){
            Yii::$app->session->addFlash('success','Record Created Successfully');
            return $this->redirect(['view','id'=>$model->id]);
        }else{
            Yii::$app->session->addFlash('error','Record Can not be Created ');
        } 
         

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'company'=>$company
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: $model->layouts->saveAs('@app/web/uploads/layouts/'.'CompanyIDMap'.'/'.$filename);

how do i put the compnay id that i have selected from the dropdown list????here

Comment: $model->layouts->saveAs('@app/web/uploads/layouts/'.$model->id.'/'.$filename);
But the saveAs() function is not creating a new folder how do i do it?

Comment: [Use FileHelper to create Folder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-filehelper)

Answer (score 0):

You should create folder first,

```
\yii\helpers\FileHelper::createDirectory(\Yii::getAlias('@app/web/uploads/layouts/'.$model->id), 0777);
```